# Get first record from joined table for each foreign key without duplicate primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
Tags:
Tag_ID | Name
1      | Tag1
2      | Tag2
3      | Tag3
4      | Tag4
5      | Tag5
6      | Tag6

Posts:
Post_ID | Title | Body
1       | Post1 | Post1
2       | Post2 | Post2
3       | Post3 | Post3
4       | Post4 | Post4
5       | Post5 | Post5
6       | Post6 | Post6
7       | Post7 | Post7
8       | Post8 | Post8
9       | Post9 | Post9
10      | Post10| Post10

TagsPosts:
Tag_ID | Post_ID
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
1      | 4
1      | 5
1      | 10
1      | 1
2      | 1
2      | 2
2      | 6
2      | 7
3      | 4
3      | 8
3      | 9
4      | 7
5      | 1
5      | 2
5      | 3
5      | 4
5      | 5
5      | 6
5      | 7
6      | 2
```

What I need to return from a query is the top 3 `Posts` for the most common `Tag` and the top 1 `Post` for the rest of the `Tags` without providing any duplicate `Posts`.

```
Desired Output:
Tag_ID | Post_ID
5      | 1
5      | 2
5      | 3
1      | 10
2      | 6
3      | 9
4      | 7
```

So far I was able to identify the top 3 `Posts` for the most common `Tag` using:

```
SELECT Top(3) t.Tag_ID, p.Post_ID FROM Tags as t
INNER JOIN TagsPosts as tp ON t.Tag_ID = tp.Tag_ID
INNER JOIN Posts as p ON tp.Post_ID = p.Post_ID
WHERE t.Tag_ID IN (
    SELECT TOP(1) Tag_ID FROM TagsPosts GROUP BY Tag_ID ORDER BY COUNT(Tag_ID) DESC)

Result:
Tag_ID | Post_ID
5      | 1
5      | 2
5      | 3
```

I also identified the top 1 `Post` for the rest of the `Tags` using:

```
SELECT t.Tag_ID, p.Post_ID FROM Tags as t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t.Tag_ID, Max(p.Post_ID) as Post_ID FROM Tags as t
INNER JOIN TagsPosts as tp ON t.Tag_ID = tp.Tag_ID
INNER JOIN Posts as p ON tp.Post_ID = p.Post_ID
WHERE t.Tag_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT TOP(1) Tag_ID FROM TagsPosts GROUP BY Tag_ID ORDER BY COUNT(Tag_ID) DESC)
    AND
p.Post_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT Top(3) p.Post_ID FROM Tags as t
    INNER JOIN TagsPosts as tp ON t.Tag_ID = tp.Tag_ID
    INNER JOIN Posts as p ON tp.Post_ID = p.Post_ID
    WHERE t.Tag_ID IN (
        SELECT TOP(1) Tag_ID FROM TagsPosts GROUP BY Tag_ID ORDER BY COUNT(Tag_ID) DESC))
    GROUP BY t.Tag_ID) as s ON t.Tag_ID = s.Tag_ID
INNER JOIN Posts as p ON s.Post_ID = p.Post_ID

Result:
Tag_ID | Post_ID
1      | 10
2      | 7
3      | 9
4      | 7
```

This is almost there, but as you can see, it returns duplicate `Posts`.

By the way, I am using SQL Server 2008 Express for testing because I am unfamiliar with MySQL, but I have been asked to determine the SQL query that can be applied to a MySQL database.  I figured if I get the basic query down in T-SQL it will be fairly simple to translate into whatever SQL is used by MySQL.

Comment: The current solution for mysql you can't test on ms sql.

Comment: Do you want to show other Post_ID instead of duplicate post or just remove that line from the output?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I was wondering if that might be the case.  Is there  a solution for MySQL that would be fairly straightforward for my first time working with MySQL?

Comment: I would like to show another non-duplicate Post_ID where possible.  If it is not possible then I will leave that Tag out of the results.

Comment: Then GROUP BY + FIRST could be a first step solution

Comment: I tried something like that, but it still returned duplicate posts.  I also tried ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY Tag_ID, but got the same result.

Comment: If you `GROUP BY Post_ID` and select `FIRST(Tag_ID)` you should be fine

Comment: can you create sqlfiddle and add few comments to your SQL. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: is a `Cursor` acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure about the cursor.  I am trying to help out a friend who is working on a web application where they need to return this content.  I'm not sure if cursors can be used when sending a query from a web application to a database.  I am more of a desktop Sql Server guy myself.

Comment: You could use the cursor to populate a temporary table. He can query the temp table every he needs that information and run the cursor once a day only. It does not seem to be a kind of data that changes dramatically..

Comment: Well I tried to create a sqlfiddle for this using MySQL and apparently MySQL is quite different from T-SQL.  I haven't been able to recreate the code above using MySQL because MySQL does not support limits in subqueries.  Looks like I'm back to the drawing board.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a windowed function, store it in a CTE, and then reference that in a predicate.  Like so (using a simplified version of your data that can run as is from SSMS).  You listed SQL-Server but not the version.  I believe table functions can run on version 2005 and higher of SQL Server but am not sure.

```
declare @Tag table ( tagid int identity, name varchar(8));

insert into @Tag values ('Tag1'),('Tag2'),('Tag3'),('Tag4'),('Tag5'),('Tag6');

declare @Posts table (postid int identity, tagid int, postbody varchar(32));

insert into @Posts values (1,'Blah'),(1, 'Blahblah'),(2, 'Blahblah'),(3, 'Blahbodyblah'),(4, 'Blahblahblah'),(4, 'Blahbodyblah'),(4, 'Blah'),(5, 'Blah'),(5, 'Blahblah'),(6, 'Blahblah');

-- use a CTE
with a as 
    (
    select 
        p.postbody
    ,   count(t.tagid) as TimesTagged
        /* You stated you wanted a return of posts based on their occurrence.  I am counting a position 
        of the COUNTS OF TAGID's descending (greatest first) starting from one.  If you have a tie and want to 
        do those I would consider using DENSE_RANK.  You would have to insert more values where you get a third 
        occurence to become a TIE to see how Rank, Dense_Rank, and Row_number differ.  They all have their 
        purposes but the user should know what they want before determining which they use.
        */
    ,   row_number() over(order by count(t.tagid) desc) as PositionOfCountsTaggedByGreatestOrderFirst
    ,   Rank() over(order by count(t.tagid) desc) as PositionOfCountsTaggedByGreatestOrderFirst_Ranking
    ,   Dense_Rank() over(order by count(t.tagid) desc) as PositionOfCountsTaggedByGreatestOrderFirst_DenseRanking
    from @Tag t 
        join @Posts p on t.tagid = p.tagid
    group by p.postbody
    )
select *
from a
-- I only use Row_Number, you can change to use one of the other predicates above if you wish.
where PositionOfCountsTaggedByGreatestOrderFirst <= 3


/*
You are stating you only want the top three counts
windowed functions are better than using top IMHO as you can specify lists 'in', medians, and all other types
explicitly defined rather than having to repeating nested selects.  The only downer is you can not use 
a predicate on a windowed function directly.  Yout must create it and then in a nested select, CTE (as shown)
, a table variable, temp table, etc...  define a predicate on it.
*/
```